# formatting amount values in cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I format my `AmountFc` property to `#,##0.00` in my view.

The property in the model is a nullable `decimal`

```
public decimal? AmountFc { get; set; }
```

And in the view I use

```
<td height="15" style="text-align:center">@Model.Transcation.AmountFc</td >
```

Using `@Model.Transcation.AmountFc.ToString("#,##0.00")` is giving the following error.

> No overload for method "ToString" takes 1 arguments

Comment: What is typeof `AmountFc`?

Comment: And what error are your getting when using `ToString()`?

Comment: it is decimal?. it gives No overload for method "ToString" takes 1 arguments when i try with ToString("#,##0.00")

Comment: Edit your question to include the relevant details (and the error is because its a nullable property)

Comment: How can I solve this

Comment: By getting an answer :) - and to do that read my last comment.

Comment: @Stephen Meucke thanks, managed with the below <td rowspan = "2" style = "text-align:center" >@(((decimal)Model.Transcation.AmountFc).ToString("#,##0.###"))  </td>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165260/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user3658516).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error your getting when using `.ToString("#,##0.###")` is because the property is a nullable value type. You would need to convert the the value to decimal, for example using

```
@Model.Transcation.AmountFc.GetValueOrDefault().ToString("#,##0.00")
```

However that means that if the value is `null`, it would display `0.00` which is misleading. You could of could conditionally check for `null`, for example

```
@if(Model.Transcation.AmountFc.HasValue)
{
    <td>@Model.Transcation.AmountFc.Value.ToString("#,##0.00")</td>
}
else
{
    <td></td>
}
```

However the better solution is to apply a [DisplayFormatAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to your property

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#,##0.00}")]
public decimal? AmountFc { get; set; }
```

and in the view, use

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Transcation.AmountFc)</td>
```

which will display the formatted value (or nothing if the value is `null`)

In addition, the `DisplayFormatAttribute` has a `NullDisplayText` property that determines what to display if the value is `null` (the default is an empty `string`), for example

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#,##0.00}", NullDisplayText = "Not applicable")]
```

would generate

```
<td>Not applicable</td>
```

if the value was `null`.